# How to Ignore wsit-client.xml when calling web service if exists

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws, wsimport, wsit

The application I am working on calls many webservice. Just recently I have intergrated another web service that requires wsit-client.xml for Soap authentication.

That is working now but all the other SOAP services have stopped working.

Whenever any of them is being called, I see messages like

```
INFO: WSP5018: Loaded WSIT configuration from file: jar:file:/opt/atlasconf/atlas.20130307/bin/soap-sdd-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/wsit-client.xml.
```

I suspect this is what is causing the Service calls to fail.

How can I cause the wsit-client.xml to be ignored for certain soap service calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by Using a Container and a Loader to configure a dynamic location for the wsit-client.xml. This way it is not automatically loaded. To do that, I first implemented a Container for the app as shown below

```
public class WsitClientConfigurationContainer extends Container {
private static final String CLIENT_CONFIG = "custom/location/wsit-client.xml";

private final ResourceLoader loader = new ResourceLoader() {
    public URL getResource(String resource) {
        return getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(CLIENT_CONFIG);
    }
};

@Override
public <T> T getSPI(Class<T> spiType) {
    if (spiType == ResourceLoader.class) {
        return spiType.cast(loader);
    } 
    return null;
}
```

}

Then to use it in the Code I do this

```
        URL WSDL_LOCATION = this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/wsdl/mysvc.wsdl");

    WSService.InitParams initParams = new WSService.InitParams();
    initParams.setContainer(new WsitClientConfigurationContainer());
    secGtwService = WSService.create(WSDL_LOCATION, SECGTWSERVICE_QNAME, initParams);
```

And it works like magic